# Livewire click error on wire:click='function(value)'

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Help please, there is a database
there are products there
For example

```
1 Name
2 Name
3 Name 
4 Name
```

everyone has links `<a wire:click="delete({{$item->id}})">Delete</a>`

When you click on link 1, 1 is deleted, then when you click on link 2, it sends a request to the server where the value is 1, although the value is specified as 2

I tried everything and I almost can’t figure out what’s going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you use a @foreach to populate the list.

You must add a distinct *wire:key* for each row that is displayed to let livewire refresh correctly the DOM:

```html
@foreach ($items as $item)

   <div wire:key="{{ 'prefix' . $item->id }}"> 

      <!-- ..... -->

      <a wire:click="delete({{$item->id}})">Delete</a>

   </div>

@endforeach
```

The *'prefix'* is not mandatory but is recommended when you have multiple lists with the same ids

[Here](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/components#adding-wirekey-to-foreach-loops) the documentation